# Message box for search box returning no results, Access 2010

Tags: vba, ms-access, ms-access-2010

I'm new to VBA, but I wanted to create a search box for a split form with multiple fields. I started out with a Macro and then ended up converting it to VBA, so there might actually be errors in the code.

Anyways, I used the apply filter command, and I would like a message box to pop up when there are no results, but this code doesn't work:

```
  Private Sub cmdSearch_Click()
        On Error GoTo cmdSearch_Click_Err
        DoCmd.ApplyFilter "", "[IDTag] Like
   ""*"" & [Forms]![Main Menu]![txtSearch] & 
     ""*"" Or [Title] Like ""*"" 
   & [Forms]![Main Menu]![txtSearch] & ""*""",""

cmdSearch_Click_Exit:
Exit Sub

cmdSearch_Click_Err:
MsgBox Error$
Resume cmdSearch_Click_Exit

End Sub
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Handling no results for docmd.applyfilter](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1730293/handling-no-results-for-docmd-applyfilter)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can tell by the syntax coloring in your question that your string construction doesn't work. It is much easier using single quotes `'`. And some variables.

```
Private Sub cmdSearch_Click()

    On Error GoTo cmdSearch_Click_Err
    Dim sSearch As String, sFilter As String

    sSearch = "'*" & [Forms]![Main Menu]![txtSearch] & "*'"
    sFilter = "[IDTag] Like " & sSearch & " Or [Title] Like " & sSearch
    Debug.Print sFilter  ' Use Ctrl+G to see Debug output

    DoCmd.ApplyFilter "", sFilter
```

For showing a MsgBox when there are no result, see the linked duplicate.

Comment: Thanks Andre! Works perfectly. I added a show all records cmd after the message box to avoid getting directed to a blank form!